# How to change download directory during test run

Tags: capybara

I have a few tests that download files and assert data inside. The problem I am facing is that the tests run in parallel so I can't delete the download directory after each test or else they delete each others files. The issue with not doing so however is that the filename includes timestamp(unique identifier) which is not known to the test so not possible to know which file to open. Is there a way to change `default_directory` for a given test in the middle of test run? The idea is to be able to tell capybara that for certain tests override the download path to be another path temporarily? I guess there could be cross wiring here too if it was possible as other tests could still be running expecting the original path to be set?

Alternatively, any suggestions on handling this?

My capybara config looks like this

```
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  preferences = {
      prompt_for_download: false,
      credentials_enable_service: false,
      default_directory: DownloadUtil::PATH
  }
  options.add_preference(:download, preferences)
  options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)
end
```

Comment: What are you using to run the tests in parallel?

Comment: `parallel_test` gem. `parallel_rspec` to be precise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most multi-process parallel test setups provide you with an environment variable you can use to configure things that need to be different between each instance of test runner (DB name, ports, etc). In the case of parallel_rspec that is `TEST_ENV_NUMBER`.  Using that you can configure the selenium/chrome instance in each test runner to use a different download directory - something like

```
preferences = {
  prompt_for_download: false,
  credentials_enable_service: false,
  default_directory: DownloadUtil::PATH + ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER']
}
```